# laravel 10 simple login can't compare passwords

Tags: laravel

users table is at default. bcrypt settings are at default.

why is it not working?

seeder:

```
'password' => Hash::make('test123')
```

controller:

```
function checklogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email',
            'password'  => 'required'
        ]);

        $user_data = array(
            'email'  => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->get('password')
        );

        if(Auth::attempt($user_data)){
            return redirect('main');
        }
        else{
            return back()->with('error', 'E-Posta Veya Şifre Yanlış Girildi!');
        }
    }
```

view:

```
                 <form method="post" action="{{ url('checklogin') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
                    </div>
                </form>
```

web.php:

```
Route::post('checklogin', 'UserController@checklogin');
```

Comment: Where in this code are you comparing passwords? What error or behavior is occurring?

Comment: this should compare my [email, plain] with the [email, bcrypt] in database Auth::attempt($user_data)

Comment: it says it's wrong credentials. i've tried comparing it myself and still returns false

Comment: Internally, it doesn't *compare*, it uses PHP's `password_verify`. Because of salting, you can't do a simple comparison between the two strings. Is this fresh code you wrote yourself, or are you working off someone else's code? In our app, we use an Eloquent mutator to *automatically* hash the password when it's set, which in your case would mean an accidental double-hashing that'd break things. It's highly unlikely the built-in `Auth::attempt()` is breaking.

Comment: i've tried Hash::check() with the hashedpassword i got from database and the plain text i'm using in seeder. that's how i got false

Comment: In Tinker, run `Hash::make('test123')`. Put that raw result in your seeder. When it seeds, do you see the exact same string in the database? Or do you see a different one?

Comment: it's generating different strings everytime

Comment: Then something in your code is re-hashing it, probably an Eloquent mutator in the `User` model, or an observer somewhere. Try just `'password' => 'test123'` in your seeder; what winds up in the database, and does your form work afterwards?

Comment: i found it thank you.

Comment: i had 'password' => 'hashed' in casts

Comment: Ah, that'll do it! Glad that helped point you in the right direction.